# JS Splice Array of Nulls Removes Last Index Regardless of Parameters

Tags: javascript

For a reason specific to this application an array of data or `null`s is used to display a list of forms. The difference is based on whether data was provided by a service or manually added, where `null` indicates everything was manually added via 
 a button not a service.

So **ignoring the use case of an array of `null`s** it turns out that `[null, null, null].splice(0, 1);` removes the `null` at index 2 instead of 0 based on entering values into the different forms displayed based on the array length, and then seeing who disappears on delete.

It can be made to work by adding something unique like `{ index: theIndex }` to the array instead of `null`.  So splice now works correctly removing the item at index 0 instead of 2, but now **I'm curious what splice does under the covers** that it can't remove an index regardless of its value compared to the other indices.

Can anyone explain what `splice` is doing?  Based on the [spec for splice](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.splice) I don't really see why this happens.

Comment: Reference: [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Thanks @KaiserKatze I've already looked at the spec attached to those docs, but I don't see why this would happen.

Comment: I don't understand. You are saying that `[null, null, null].splice(0, 1)` removes the 3rd `null` instead of the 1st one. But how can you tell? Null values are standard primitive values--what I try to say is that `null === null` same as `0 === 0`. So *there would be no difference* if you removed the 3rd `null` or the 1st one from an array of `null`s.

Comment: When I try `['a', 'b', 'c'].splice(0, 1);`, it yields `['a']`.

Comment: @mauroc8 maybe reread the question I know since it displays forms I can enter data into and I can see which one is deleted

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. Do you expect to get `[undefined, null, null]` ? Then splice is not what you need, but the [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

Comment: @KaiserKatze sure does, but `[null, null, null].splice(0,1)` is the reason for the question I already know how to use splice, but this was an error I spent a bunch of time finding and fixing that I was just curious why it was happening

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem in actual output. This really sounds like an XY problem

Comment: Hereby I quote `based on entering values into the forms and seeing who disappears on delete.`, could this be a result from your framework and its model-view mapping?

Comment: @mauroc8 no I expect that the forms displayed based on the array length (1 form per indice) would be removed using splice on that index and not always the last form in the array

Comment: @mtpultz, I don't know which code is in charge of mapping the array to the forms.Depending on this, there's gotta be some way of telling that script which form you want deleted. If the code saves a copy of the array before and after some edition, maybe it is comparing to see which element changes.

Comment: @KaiserKatze I'm using Angular and an `*ngFor="let form of forms; let i=index"` and invoke `remove(i)` on button click, which calls `this.forms.splice(i, 1);`, which will always remove the last array item for an array of `[null, null, null]` indicating 3 forms were added by clicking add form, which invokes `this.forms.push(null)` each time

Comment: @mtpultz perhaps you should try to improve your data structure, an array of `null` gives little info about mapping between model and view. I suggest you use a list of dicts, such as `[ { index: 1, value: null } ]`.

Comment: @mauroc8 like I said it is weird, and I noted in the question that I fixed it using an object with a key/value pair so just  a really weird use case that made me wonder what kind of comparison splice does under the covers

Comment: @KaiserKatze yah I know that's why I said I fixed it using an object with a key/value pair and that the use case should be ignored since it is weird.  I really was just curious how splice works under the covers so that's why I was reading the spec, but couldn't figure it out

Comment: @mtpultz it's always a bad idea to directly remove or add elements in the array if it maps to your model.

Comment: @KaiserKatze I think this is just a weird use case that uncovered something in `splice` regarding an array of `null` values that has a weird edge case that I was interested in finding out why it might be happening

Comment: @mtpultz But you did fix the problem by improving the data structure and mapping mode, I think `splice` is innocent in this use case. I blame the previous mapping mode. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This follows from the comments in the question but is too large to be a comment).

So I think you are having a conceptual misconception (^^). Look at this examples:

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3]
a.splice(0, 1) // => 1
a // => [2, 3]

let b = [1, 2, 3]
delete b[0] // => true
b // => [<1 empty slot>, 2, 3]
```

The `splice` function modifies the array *in-place*. Note that, although we spliced the first element, we got as a result an array of two elements.

Look now at this example

```
let a = [1, 1, 1]
a.splice(0, 1)
a // => [1, 1]
let b = [1, 1, 1]
b.splice(2, 1)
b // => [1, 1]
```

We are deleting the first element from `a` and the last from `b`, but of course there's no way of telling so just looking at the result.

In the case with the `null`s, the same thing is happening. Some library (Angular) is trying to figure out which element you deleted, but there's no way of knowing. This is because `null === null`.

Now if you use an array of empty objects, for example, there *would be a way of knowing*. Since `{} !== {}`---because each time you cast a `{}` you are creating a *unique object*---, then you could know which element is missing in an array of empty objects. The case is similar with the array `[1, 2, 3]`.

```
let a = [{}, {}, {}] // lets imagine that each object has a unique id
                     // and we have [{}#1, {}#2, {}#3]
let [obj1, obj2, obj3] = a
obj1 === obj2 // => false, because they have different ids.

a.splice(0, 1)
a // => [{}#2, {}#3]
a.includes(obj1) // => false, because {}#1 is no longer in a
```

So an alternative to using an array of `null`s, would be to use an array of empty objects. I think that is why the code works for you when you use objects like `{ index: theIndex }`. But of course all depends on how smart Angular is. I bet there is a more native way of deleting an element, as @KaiserKatze points out, "it's always a bad idea to directly remove or add elements in the array if it maps to your model."

You have to understand that when you are splicing the array you're only doing that--removing an element from an array. *You're not removing the "form element" when splicing the array*. Instead, some foreign code is reading the array and trying to figure out --under the hood-- what you intended to do.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right about it being something related to how Angular determines what index was removed, and that seems more likely then splice having an issue